# relation between union and intersection

Tags: elementary-set-theory

A and B are any two sets.
if A U B ≠ B
is it also true that A ∩ B ≠ A ?
and if so then why?

This is just a step I am using for a bigger proof, if the above is not true then I'll have to search for a different direction.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If $A \cup B \ne B$, this means that $A \cup B$ is "bigger" than $B$, i.e. there is some $x \in A$ such that $x \notin B$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $A\cup B\ne B$, then there is some $a\in A$ such that $a\notin B$, so $a\notin (A\cap B)$, so $A\cap B\ne A$.

Answer (score 3):

It's easier to prove this the other way round, i.e. you can show that

> if $A\cap B=A$, then $A\cup B=B$.

This is easy to show. The fact that $A\cap B = A$ implies that $A\subseteq B$, which also directly means that $A\cup B = B$.

Or, if you want the traditional long way round:

- Let $b\in A\cup B$.

  - Then, if $b\in B$, we are done
  - If $b\in A$, then $b\in A\cap B$ (because $A=A\cap B$) which means that $b\in B$
- Therefore, if $b\in A\cup B$, then $b\in B$, which means that $A\cup B\subseteq B$
- We also know that (always) $B\subseteq A\cup B$
- We conclude that $B=A\cup B$

Comment: but saying that if  A∪B=B also means that  A∩B=A does not mean that the opposite is true as well that if  A∪B≠B means A ∩ B ≠ A.

Comment: @eventhorizon02 That's not what I said. If you had read my answer carefully, you would notice I said that $A\cap B=A\implies A\cup B=B$ is the same as $A\cup B\neq B \implies A\cap B\neq A$. I did **NOT** say what you are saying. What I said is simple basic logic, i.e. that $P\implies Q$ is equivalent to $\neg Q \implies \neg P$

Comment: eventhorizon02: If $P := A\cup B \neq B$, and $Q :=A\cap B \neq A$, so you are trying to prove the implication $P\to Q$.  But as 5xum notes, any implication is equivalent to it's contrapositive.  The contrapositive of $P\to Q$ is $\lnot Q \to \lnot P$.  Proving either form of the implication proves the implication.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is true. $A \cup B \neq B$ means $\exists x \in A \setminus B$ (otherwise, we would have $ A \subset B$ which implies $A \cup B = B$).

And since $x \not\in B$, $x \not \in A \cap B$ while $x \in A$